# how to prevent my ajax parameter from holding php 'header()' value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create a client-side and server-side check. These checks will look for empty names, invalid names, already taken names etc.

however my problem: my parameter is given the argument of the header, and therefore the user won't be redirected, it will only show code.

quick example:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'signup.php',
type: 'POST',
data: data,
success: function(response) {
    window.location.href = response;
  }
});
```

PHP code:

```
 if(empty($loginName)) {
  header('Location: index.php?loginName=empty');
  exit();
}
```

So what I would like to have, but won't work (this is to give you an idea of what I am trying to do):

```
 if(empty($loginName)) {
  index.php?loginName=empty //and this should be the response argument
  header('Location: index.php?loginName=empty');
  exit();
}
```

My response parameter would have the argument of the header + the header content, so it will only generate html code. (I used console.log() to see what response held as argument). I can however take away the header tag and just use a string, my response will work then, but what I would like to have is the following: I would like to keep the header() function, but I want my response to redirect me correctly based on what the header() content is.
I already tried using a string and the header() function seperately, but this didn't work, unfortunately.

So expected result would be (if loginName were to be empty) that response holds a string with: index.php?loginName=empty, but without removing the header() function.

Comment: Why can't you remove the `header` redirect if this is intended to be used by AJAX calls? Can't you just return a JSON response?

Comment: I could, however I want to keep the headers in case someone tries accessing the PHP page by entering it directly into the URL.

Comment: jQuery (and most other popular AJAX libraries) sends a `X-Requested-With` header with AJAX requests, which you can detect and serve a different response to. If you're using a framework, it probably has something for this built-in; Laravel has a `Request::isJson()` check for example.

Comment: You don't get to send a text response and a redirection. Pick one and work with it.

Comment: Sorry, correction: Laravel's function is `Request::ajax()`.